# Using higer order function to override abstract method in java

Tags: java, java-8, higher-order-functions

In an abstract class i have the following definitions:

```
  protected abstract A expectedA(B b);

  protected Function<A, B> createExpectedA(Long foo) {
    return a -> { ... return b}}
```

And then I want to override the abstract function with the return function from `createExpectedA` like so:

```
  @Override
  protected Function<A, B> expectedA = createExpectedA(fee);
```

However this gives me the following error:

> The annotation @Override is disallowed for this location

**How can I do what I want abowe in Java8?**

Comment: Do you know the "normal" way to use @Override?

Comment: The return type  of `protected abstract A expectedA(B b)` does not match the return type of `protected Function<A, B> expectedA = createExpectedA(fee)`. Start by fixing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annotation `Override` is meant to be used on methods not on fields, that is why you get this error. As reminder, here is the Javadoc:

> Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method
>   declaration in a supertype. If a method is annotated with this
>   annotation type compilers are required to generate an error message
>   unless at least one of the following conditions hold:
>
> - The method does override or implement a method declared in a supertype.
> - The method has a signature that is override-equivalent to that of any public method declared in Object.

What you want to do seem to be something like this:

```
@Override
protected A expectedA(B b) {
    return createExpectedA(fee).apply(b);
}
```